# Three dice are rolled. What is the probability of obtaining at least one 6?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The approach in the text is using the "not" rule, where we first find the probability of getting zero number of 6's. For one dice this probability is $\frac{5}{6}$ and for three die it becomes $\frac{5}{6}^3$. Hence using the not rule the probability of getting at least one 6 is $1-\frac{125}{216} = \frac{91}{216}$.
But I have a different approach which leads to a different answer - 
Let's say we have one dice then we have just 1 way to get atleast one 6. For two die, it becomes 6 ways and for three die the answer comes to be 36 ways. Hence the probability turns out to be $\frac{36}{216}$.
What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: For three dice you could have $6XX, X6X, XX6$ where $X$ stands for any non-six.  that's already $3\times 5^2=75$ possibilities and this is not the full list.  Where did you get $36$?

Comment: The correct answer is $91/216$. Note that $36/216$ is a fancy way to write $1/6$: this is the probability that the first die is $6$. But the event "at least one six" is larger than that.

Comment: I know that my answer is wrong but what is wrong with my answer? I want atleast one 6 so I will fix one die with 6 and there are total 36 ways for the other two die

Comment: You come out with 36 because you fix one die, say die 1 and assign its value to 6. This means that dice 2 and 3 can each assume 6 values. Then in the denominator you consider cases where each die can assume 6 values. So in the numerator you are not considering cases where for example die 1 is 3, die 2 is 4, die 3 is 6

Comment: "For two die (sic), it becomes 6 ways..." looks like where you went wrong. There are 11 ways: (1,6) (2,6) (3,6) (4,6) (5,6) (6,6) (6,5) (6,4) (6,3) (6,2) (6,1)

Comment: Before you go and say that the dice are indistinguishable and so $(1,6)$ and $(6,1)$ are effectively the same... I'm going to stop you right there and say that this is an incorrect train of logic.  *Even if* the dice were in fact indistinguishable, because we prefer working in equiprobable sample spaces it is preferable to *pretend* the dice were in fact distinguishable as this allows us to calculate more easily.  Even barring that, although there are indeed six different *recognizable* outcomes in the case they were two indistinguishable dice that doesn't mean there are $36$ for three dice...

Comment: I recommend reading my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321361/why-is-flipping-a-head-then-a-tail-a-different-outcome-than-flipping-a-tail-then/3321368#3321368) with regards to the incorrect argument that the dice being indistinguishable should lead to a different answer.  If that *wasn't* your argument, then I can only imagine you came up with your numbers then by incorrectly mistaking the problem of "The probability *at least one* die is a six" with "The probability the **first** die is a six."

Comment: One 'die', several 'dice' for gambling. 'Dies' for manufacturing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Let's say we have one die then we have just 1 way to get at least one 6": yes, $1$ out of $6$ outcomes.

"For two dice, it becomes 6 ways". Nope, you have $1$ way to get a double 6, and $10$ ways to get only one 6 (first die: 6, second die: 1-5; first die= 1-5, second die: 6). $1+10=11$ out of $36$ outcomes.

"for three dice the answer comes to be 36 ways". Nope, you have $1$ way to get three 6s, $15$ ways to get two 6s (three times five ways: 6, 6, 1-5; 6, 1-5, 6; 1-5, 6, 6), $75$ ways to get only one 6 (three times twentyfive ways: 6, 1-5, 1-5; 1-5, 6, 1-5; 1-5, 1-5, 6). $1+15+75=91$ out of $216$ outcomes.

Hence even not using the (easier) not rule the probability of getting at least one 6 is $\frac{91}{216}$ :)

Answer (score 1):

That approach is wrong.
Although your answer for only one die is correct you are missing  some possibilities incase of two and three dies.
**Let me tell you what you are missing**.

1. In case of second die you are missing one of the two possibilities eg (1,6),(6,1).
2. **Actually there are 11 cases**.

   $$1*5 + 5*1 + 1 =11$$
3. When three die appear there is chance of 6 appears only on one or two or on all dies. You need to add all the cases. If you just multply you will miss $(*,*,6)$. (* Represent any number other than 6.)

Now for three dies in your way if you agree with corrected case of two dies there will be $$6*11=66$$ ways. Which is **wrong** *But it could be corrected by adding missing cases*

**Let us add missing case**

$(*,*,6)$  have 5x5 = 25 cases

**Now total cases will be**
$$66+25=91$$

**Now probability will be** $$\frac{91}{216}$$

*You may want to note that the case such as $(6,6,6),(6,*,6),(*,6,6)$ had included in your way of multiplying the two die case with six*.