# Why is the probability of 3 coins landing heads 1/8?

Tags: probability

The probability of a single coin landing heads is $1/2$.
Using simple probability theory, this means that the probability of three coins landing heads is $1/2*1/2*1/2=1/8$

However, if we **don't enumerate or distinguish** the coins, the possible end combinations we see after flipping all three coins are
TTT
TTH
THH
HHH
Since one of these four is our desired combination of three heads, the probability would seem to be $1/4$.

Why isn't this the case?

Comment: Those four outcomes are not equi-probable.

Comment: There are four possibilities, but they are not equally probable.  There are three ways to get two tails and one head, while only one way to get three heads.

Comment: THT, HTT,HTH,HHT also have to considered.  Sequence matters.

Comment: Nice question! And nice comment too.

Comment: No. OP says the coins are indistinguishable, @herb steinberg

Comment: The coins are distinct in reality.  Thus, they need to get distinguished for a meaningful analysis.

Comment: Tow coins are only not distinguishable if they can be at the same place at the same time. But then they are in fact one coin only.

Comment: It could be one coin flipped three times - the sequence of outcomes is what matters.

Comment: I recommend reading my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321361/why-is-flipping-a-head-then-a-tail-a-different-outcome-than-flipping-a-tail-then/3321368#3321368).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the cases TTH, THT and HTT are distinct because despite the coins are equal, the order of their toss matters (i.e. knowing that exactly 1 head drew is not enough, we must know at which toss did it happen).