# What is the probability of having only heads in two tosses knowing that first or second toss contains head.

Tags: probability, statistics

Im looking for an answer and I found many similar answers but the difference is that you do not know if first or second throw contains H.
When I think normally if you have one H and toss then you have 1/2 probability of having T and 1/2 of another H so: HH if XH or HX (also how to simply describe such probability??).
But book PROBABILITY AND RANDOM PROCESSES gives answer such as 1/3.
Here is why:
We have set - {HH, TH, HT, TT}
Then you pull out TT cause it does not meet the condition.
{HH, TH, HT}
so its 1/3.
But my questions are: shouldn't such set reduce to a set where order HT TH doesn't matter? -> {HH, TH} -> P(HH) = 1/2. Shouldn't we also compute it like that: 1. There is one H given. So there is 1/2 chance of it being Hx and 1/2 of xH. Also both have probability of being HH = 1/2. Hence: P(HH | Hx or xH) = 1/2 * 1/2 + 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4+1/4 = 1/2.

Would be glad if somebody with experience checked. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a rephrasing of the standard [Boy Girl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_girl_paradox)

Comment: Thank you, I got stuck for almost hour with it finding 2 possible answers.

Comment: First, [Why is flipping a head then a tail a different outcome than flipping a tail then a head?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321361/why-is-flipping-a-head-then-a-tail-a-different-outcome-than-flipping-a-tail-then/3321368#3321368).  Second, as alluded to this is [the boy-girl problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/in-a-family-with-two-children-what-are-the-chances-if-one-of-the-children-is-a/15269#15269).

Comment: The punchline at the end of the day is that this is a very nuanced question which is easy to interpret incorrectly.  There are many ways to interpret the question that lead to an answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ but such interpretations do not necessarily match the intended interpretation.  Read more on the wiki link and the duplicate question about more of these slightly altered question statements and why it leads to different answers.